# configure symfony2 to send email after getting exception in prod mode

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, monolog

Im working on a project using symfony2, I uploaded it on the web, and turn it from the dev mode to the prod mode, I've done some testing, and when I got an exception, it sent me 3O email on my inbox, there is my config_prod code :
**NOTE:** Im using monolog for logging

```
 imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

   #framework:
   #    validation:
   #        cache: apc

doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      grouped
        grouped:
            type:       group
            members:    [streamed, swift]
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        swift:
            type:           swift_mailer
            from_email:     FQN@foo.com
            to_email:       a.krachli@improvia-maroc.com
            subject:        "GESTIBAT::Error_Exception"
            level:          debug
        login:
            type:           stream
            path:           "%kernel.logs_dir%/auth.log"
            level:          info
            channels:       security
```

If someone has an idea, Thanks for help!

Comment: try changing the `level` to `critical`

Comment: Probabily you receive the debug message also. Try to set to critical the error message level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should buffer logger messages before sending them as it is described in [symfony2  documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html)

```
buffered:
  type:    buffer
  handler: swift
```